# Laravel Routing: page you are looking for could not be found

Tags: php, routes, laravel-5

I have a defined a rout in Laravel but when i call the route I Get 404 (Sorry, the page you are looking for could not be found.)

The Route is: `einlagerungen/{$paletten_id}/bei_paletten_id`

## Route Definitions

```
Route::get('/', function () {
    return view('welcome');
});

Route::get('einlagerungen/{$paletten_id}/bei_paletten_id', [
   'as'=>'einlagerungen/bei_paletten_id', 'uses'=>'EinlagerungRestController@beiPalettenId'
]);
```

## Controller Code

```
class EinlagerungRestController extends Controller
{
    ...

    public function beiPalettenId($paletten_id)
    {   
        return "it works";
    }

    ....

}
```

Comment: Not sure if that's the problem, but you don't need a dollar sign in your route definition. Try: `Route::get('einlagerungen/{paletten_id}/bei_paletten_id', ....`

Comment: Try without `$`. `einlagerungen/{paletten_id}/bei_paletten_id`

Comment: Try with slash and without dollar sign :
Route::get('/einlagerungen/{paletten_id}/bei_paletten_id, [
'as'=>'einlagerungen/bei_paletten_id', 'uses'=>'EinlagerungRestController@beiPalettenId']);

Comment: @Amarnasan You don't need the slash at the front in your Route definitions.

Answer (score 2):

You don't need dollar sign

Try

```
Route::get('einlagerungen/{paletten_id}/bei_paletten_id', [
   'as'=>'einlagerungen/bei_paletten_id', 'uses'=>'EinlagerungRestController@beiPalettenId'
]);
```

http://laravel.com/docs/5.1/routing#required-parameters